# Существует ли слово НАРУШИМ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, словоизменение

Встретился оборот:

> зимний покой не нарушим

Ни один словарь не дает ответа, существует ли слово "нарушим" и как оно употребляется.

Comment: Я нарушу,  ты нарушишь, мы нарушим... нет?

Comment: Оборот оборотом, но нельзя ли по секрету всю строчку, фразу?

Comment: Сколько копий сломано зря! И все из-за отсутствия одного слова. Напиши Ирина "будет зимний покой не нарушим" — все бы прояснилось.

Answer (score 2):

[нару́шить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)
Глагол, совершенный вид, переходный; соответствующий глагол несовершенного вида — наруша́ть.
Мы нарушим — 1 лицо, мн. ч., будущее время.

*Мы всё простим — и не **нарушим**

Покоя девственниц весны,

Огонь божественный потушим,

Прогоним ласковые сны.*
А. Блок

**Дополнение**

Вот у того же Блока используется краткая форма от *ненарушимый*:

*Покидай бессилье мирозданья,

Твой покой теперь **ненарушим.**

Предо мною — грань богопознанья,

Неизбежный сумрак, черный дым.*

А вот и краткая форма от *нарушимый* обнаружилась! (Ударение обозначено мной.)

*Вновь за окном весной повеяло,

Цветет вечерняя заря.

Как хорошо сейчас в Дивееве

За стенами монастыря.*

*Там синь над храмом не колышется,

Покой **ничем не наруши́м.**

И многих горюшко услышится

Там, где почи́ет Серафим.*
[Н. Б. Рачков](http://rodnayaladoga.ru/index.php/poeziya/1190-tolko-by-angel-letel-i-letel)

Comment: То ли ударение Ирина делает?

Comment: @Ирина Тогда неплохо было бы указать ударение в вопросе!

Comment: @Сибиряк  Речь шла вообще о слове. Иное ударение стало сюрпризом

Comment: Какое ударение по вашей версии иное?

Comment: @Сибиряк  В стихотворении чётко слышно ударение: не нарУшим. Тогда как верно по мнению всех авторов: ненарушИм.

Comment: О каком стихотворении речь? В ответе их три. И самое главное, о чем вас уже спрашивали, но ответа так и не дождались: какое ударение в вашем вопросе?

Comment: @Сибиряк Разумеется, об оригинальном, откуда и взята строчка (Застывает земля...).  Как обьясняю, точное ударение не известно. Потому и спрашивала о возможности любых вариантов. Благодаря сайту получила полный развернутый ответ.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова  Только благодаря вашему ответу, восходящему к Блоку, можно говорить о том, что и в оригинальном стихотворении форма слова и ударение проставлены верно:
Мы всё простим — и не нарушим
Покоя девственниц весны,
Огонь божественный потушим,
Прогоним ласковые сны.

Answer (score 0):

Полный вариант прилагательного, **нарушимый** (такой, что может нарушаться), встречается в некоторых словарях и в разных книгах, например:

> *... право есть порядок, существующий как частный результат воли и
>   сознания отдельных групп людей и потому случайный, изменчивый и
>   **нарушимый**.* (Эмпирические законы деятельности русского суда присяжных,
>   А.М. Бобрищев-Пушкин, 1896)

Более употребителен вариант с отрицанием, **ненарушимый**,

> 2. Ничем не прерываемый, не нарушаемый. Ненарушимый покой. Ненарушимая тишина.

для которого в *словаре Ушакова* приводится также и краткий вариант **ненаруши́м**. Раздельное или слитное написание этого слова, как обычно, должно зависеть от контекста (*отрицание* свойства нарушимости - раздельно; *утверждение* ненарушимости - слитно):  это может быть о "*ненарушимости* зимнего покоя"; менее естественно предположить, что этими словами кто-то оспаривает высказанную собеседником "*нарушимость* зимнего покоя". Отсюда видна *употребимость* данного слова, хотя и ограниченная редкой надобностью.

Comment: В словаре Ушакова в сети (https://ushakovdictionary.ru/view_search.php) нет такого слова. Есть другой вариант словаря?

Comment: Судя по всему, мы имеем дело с уже устаревшей формой применения слова. Из разбора видно, что ранее оно было вполне себе применимо.

Comment: @М_Г Это его _толковый_ словарь: https://biblioclub.ru/?page=dict&dict_id=117 В полной форме слово есть у Даля и разных совр. составителей.

Answer (score 0):

[Застывает земля...](https://stihi.ru/2012/10/29/7007)

Ирина Тамиранова

> Застывает земля, погружаясь в морозную негу,
>   И дрожат тополя в белых искрах октябрьского снега.
>   Там, где дождь был вчера, видно наледь, сковавшую лужи.
>   Подступает пора, и твой голос немного простужен.
>   А в закатных лучах так щедры кисти горькой рябины!
>   И горят на ветвях, как гирлянды огней негасимых.
>   Застывает земля, будет зимний покой **не нарушим**...
>   Но дрожат тополя, - ты их шёпот прощальный послушай.

Как видим, имеется в виду краткая форма прилагательного *нарушимый*, но тут проблема и с ударением, и с раздельным написанием *не*. Да и есть ли такое вообще? Мне не удалось найти его в словарях. Я бы уж лучше написал "не нарушен".

Comment: И убедительно, и логично. Однако, у языка своя внутренняя логика и мелодика. И слово нарушЕН -не полноценная замена, увы.